# Filtering columns from a timeseries based on unique start and end dates [R] (to standardize row 1 as day one for each)

Tags: r, date, transformation

I'm trying to standardize the start dates for columns in table `timeseries` so that each one starts based on predefined values I have in another table `StartEnd`. `datetime` in `timeseries` is in POSIXct format as are all date values in this problem.

How would I create a data frame where each column's first row begins with the values at `Start` and while also removing 0 values at `End`? This is after having spread() on a stacked dataset:

`timeseries <- spread(timeseries, ID, Count , fill = "0")`

I've looked into filters, but I'm not sure if dplyr would be the go-to here. I think a function of some sort could work out, but with my limited knowledge, I don't know what the structure of one would look like in this context. Jfyi I'm self-taught in R with no formal education in coding other than some Coursera courses.

`timeseries`:

```
    datetime          ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7
1   01/01/19 00:00:00   0   0   7   1   1   0   0
2   01/01/19 01:00:00   0   0   11  2   2   0   0
3   01/01/19 02:00:00   0   0   6   3   3   0   0
4   01/01/19 03:00:00   3   0   10  0   4   0   0
5   01/01/19 04:00:00   4   0   3   0   5   0   0
6   01/01/19 06:00:00   5   1   1   0   6   0   1
7   01/01/19 07:00:00   6   2   1   0   7   0   3
8   01/01/19 09:00:00   0   3   2   0   0   1   0
9   01/01/19 10:00:00   1   4   3   0   0   2   1
```

`StartEnd`:

```
SomeID   Start              End
ID1      01/01/19 03:00:00  01/01/19 10:00:00 
ID2      01/01/19 06:00:00  01/01/19 10:00:00
ID3      01/01/19 00:00:00  01/01/19 10:00:00 
ID4      01/01/19 00:00:00  01/01/19 02:00:00
ID5      01/01/19 00:00:00  01/01/19 07:00:00
ID6      01/01/19 09:00:00  01/01/19 10:00:00
ID7      01/01/19 06:00:00  01/01/19 10:00:00
```

Expected output:

```
    ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7
1   3   1   7   1   1   1   1
2   4   2   11  2   2   2   3
3   5   3   6   3   3       0
4   6   4   10      4       1
5   0       3       5       
6   1       1       6       
7           1       7       
8           2               
9           3
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: Updated with the expected output, apologies it's not clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get `timeseries` in long format, join it with  `StartEnd` dataframe, convert datetime columns into `POSIXct` format, `filter` the values which are between `Start` and `End` and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

timeseries %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -datetime, names_to = 'SomeID') %>%
  left_join(StartEnd, by = 'SomeID') %>%
  mutate_at(vars(datetime, Start, End), lubridate::dmy_hms) %>%
  filter(datetime >= Start & datetime <= End) %>%
  select(SomeID, value) %>%
  group_by(SomeID) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = SomeID, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  select(paste0("ID", 1:7))

# A tibble: 9 x 7
#    ID1   ID2   ID3   ID4   ID5   ID6   ID7
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     3     1     7     1     1     1     1
#2     4     2    11     2     2     2     3
#3     5     3     6     3     3    NA     0
#4     6     4    10    NA     4    NA     1
#5     0    NA     3    NA     5    NA    NA
#6     1    NA     1    NA     6    NA    NA
#7    NA    NA     1    NA     7    NA    NA
#8    NA    NA     2    NA    NA    NA    NA
#9    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! 
The only note I'll make is that I had already formatted the time column beforehand and in order for this to work, it needs to be unformatted.